# How to prevent errors with large results when using eval()?

Tags: python, eval

I'm making a calculator in Python and am currently trying to prevent the program crashing when dealing with large input.

The only way I know how to catch errors is using 'try' and 'except', so I wrote this:

```
def solve(self, equation):
    try:
        return eval(equation)
    except(OverflowError):
        messagebox.showinfo("Error","Result too large")
    return equation
```

(I'm aware `eval` can be dangerous but the user is unable to type any input so I think it's fine)

When I input a massive number in scientific notation like `'389e+10**(58)*9'` the `OverflowError` is caught successfully, but if I put in something like `'55555555**5555555'` the window stops responding.

I was under the impression the latter also raises an `OverflowError` but I now I think this is could be happening because it doesn't create an error at all, and `eval` just can't handle working out a result this large.

If this is the case, I think I should put a limit on how large the answer should be, but I'm unsure of how I would decide on this limit. Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean “the user is unable to type any input”?

Comment: The user puts in the figures to evaluate using the tkinter buttons only. They are unable to type anything using their keyboard. Sorry for being unclear!

Comment: Like gmds said, this is pretty hard to solve :) Do you need exact answers, or are the same kinds of approximations you’d find on a physical calculator good enough?

Comment: You can run the `eval` in a separate thread, and timeout if it doesn't produce the result in some time.

Comment: Upon reading gmds' answer I've realized I should've been more specific with my question. As I said in the comment I left there, I was mostly just trying to figure out what was happening, which has now been explained to me. Thank you so much for your response, I'll be sure to be more specific with my answers in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python, `float` is usually a 64-bit floating point number, which can hold a finite range. Values above that cause an `OverflowError` to be raised. As `389e+10` returns a `float`, the entire expression `389e+10**(58)*9` also returns a `float`.

On the other hand, `55555555**5555555` returns an `int`. In Python, `int` can hold arbitrarily large values, limited only by memory. Therefore, what is happening is that Python attempts to calculate a really big number, taking a really, really long time to do so.

This is, in general, not that easy of a question to solve, because you're using `eval`, and therefore you have no information about the exact nature of the equation.

I would suggest instead parsing the equation, which will allow you to inspect it in detail. You could then, among other things, not perform exponentiation calculations where both the base and exponent are large.

(or you could just use floating point calculation for everything, which will affect precision, but I don't think that really matters for a simple calculator, right?)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I understand what is happening now. I'm sorry for not being clearer in my question. I was really just confused about why the two input were dealt with definitely (which you have cleared up for me). It is just a simple calculator so it's working fine with floating point calculation ^_^

Comment: @user11319372 Sure, but remember that if you just call `eval` like that, the input will still be interpreted as an `int`, regardless of whether you plan to convert it to a `float` later or not. You'll need to make sure that all calculations are done as `float`.

Answer (score 0):

It stops responding because it is busy calculating `55555555**5555555`.  It won't produce an OverflowError because integers in Python are arbitrary precision.  It will keep getting larger and larger, taking more and more memory, until it cripples your computer, which it has done.